# Ошибка записи в базу данных - php

Tags: php, sql

php

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'user' (login,password,email) VALUES('$login','$password1','$emails')";
```

не дает записать строку в таком виде, как исправить? почему подсвечивает? в чем ошибка и как её решить? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кто там что подсвечивает? почитайте про передачу параметров в запрос. а имена полей, если выделяются, то обычно обратными кавычками а не обычными.

Comment: @teran , так он и не выделял имена полей ни в кавычки, ни в апострофы

Comment: @Dmitry_allread_return а что-то у меня было "полей и таблиц", но куда то потерялось